# Como mostrar o indicador de loading no Swift 4 com o WKViewWeb

Tags: swift

Olá, estou tentando mostrar o indicador de loading enquanto minha página está sendo lida, mas não funcionou. Pesquisei na internet, mas não tem o código completo e sou iniciante no Swift. Podem ajudar?

```
import UIKit
import WebKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, WKNavigationDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var indicador1: UIActivityIndicatorView!
@IBOutlet weak var webview: WKWebView!
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    loadadress()
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
func loadadress(){

    let url: URL = URL(string: "http://www.google.com.br")!
    let urlRequest: URLRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
    webview.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false;
    webview.scrollView.bounces = false;
    webview.load(urlRequest)
}

func webViewDidStartLoad(_: UIWebView){
    indicador1.startAnimating()
}
func webViewdDidFinishLoad(_:UIWebView){

    indicador1.stopAnimating()
}

}
```

Comment: Como está o `UIActivityIndicatorView` na view? Ele aparece mas não anima ou ele nem aparece? Poderia verificar também, por favor, se durante a execução, os métodos  `webViewDidStartLoad` e `webViewdDidFinishLoad` executam?

Comment: ele está na View por cima do webview, o debug não passa pela função didstart e nem didfinish, coloquei um print nessas funções e não gerou nada no console. Quando ativo o indicador manualmente eu vejo por cima da webview e fica ativado.

Comment: Certo, então tente implementar o `didFinish` do `WKNavigationDelegate` e chame o `indicador1.stopAnimating()` nele. Aí o `indicador1.startAnimating()` você pode chamar logo depois do `webview.load(urlRequest)` na sua função `loadadress()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Caro colega,

Existem 2 questões que você tem que observar ao iniciar o loading e parar ele:

1 - Ele inicia como hidden?, se sim você precisa adicionar:

```
indicador1.startAnimating()
indicador1.isHidden = false
```

2 - Se isso já foi feito o segundo ponto é que toda essa parte de iteração de tela tem que rodar na thread principal, tenta adicionar o seguinte codigo:

No start loading:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    indicador1.startAnimating()
    indicador1.isHidden = false      
}
```

No stop loading:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    indicador1.stopAnimating()
    indicador1.isHidden = true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu caso, ele não entra nos métodos pois você não disse para sua WKWebView associar o delegate dele com os que tais implementando nessa classe. Pra resolver isso, só fazer isso:

```
webview.delegate = self
```

A partir daí, a sua webview irá chamar os métodos que você está implementando nessa classe quando os delegates da webview forem acionados.

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou.